# how to set datepicker default date to custom date in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i change datepicker default date to custom date.this is working correctly,
but i want empty text field in starting time.
similar useful code is
    http://jsfiddle.net/DwT8M/
my example code is
    http://plnkr.co/edit/H7vezOLLPkTSp085v7wa?p=preview

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/DwT8M/
  [2]: http://plnkr.co/edit/H7vezOLLPkTSp085v7wa?p=preview
```

Comment: do you need any help here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DwT8M/    this plunker starting text field empty.

Comment: i want same empty text in my code http://plnkr.co/edit/H7vezOLLPkTSp085v7wa?p=preview

Comment: please help me pankajparkar this one

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/H7vezOLLPkTSp085v7wa?p=preview  in starting the datepicker text box empty.i want empty field in starting time.click the field show custom date(2013-11-20).please help me.

Comment: Im looking at it.don't worry